# Firebase login not working with nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login to my app using NodeJS to perform some operations, I don't think I need admin access since I only want to read data locally:

```
var config = {
    /*my config fields*/
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var email = "demo@gmail.com";
var password = "demodemo";

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function (error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("Problem with Firebase:");
        console.log(error.code + ": " + error.message);
    });
```

but it return `auth/wrong-password: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.` which is not accurate. There is probably an error but it's not the password since I can login using using the same ids for example with my Android app.

Any idea of missing configuration or limitation of Firebase here? Thanks

Comment: Are you using cloud functions?

Comment: The only operations I want to do are: login and read data (so auth and database module). I succeeded to do this using admin right but I would prefer to keep a login if possible.

Comment: When the server gives that response it is typically correct. Are you sure your configuration points to the project where you created the user account?

Comment: I use the configuration that firebase generate in the console, and this seems to be fine since I can access the project when I switch to admin mode.